# Change RadGrid columns headers

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radgrid

I tried to use the following code snippet in the PreRender event to change the HeaderText but it is not working.
Actually, I just noticed `RadGrid1.columns` was empty (with a break point) but my RadGrid has 3 columns:

```
protected void RadGrid1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridColumn col in RadGrid1.Columns)
    {
        if (col.UniqueName == "idAgir")
            col.HeaderText = "Numéro";
        if (col.UniqueName == "objet")
            col.HeaderText = "Titre du Ticket";
        if (col.UniqueName == "dateEtatIncident")
            col.HeaderText = "Date dernière intervention";
    }
    RadGrid1.Rebind(); 
}
```

Comment: your way will work if you'll change RadGrid1.Columns to RadGrid1.MasterTableView.Columns

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var masterTableView = RadGrid1.MasterTableView;
var column = masterTableView.GetColumn("idAgir");
column.HeaderText = "Numéro";
masterTableView.Rebind();
```

Comment: Thanks it works! but why mine is wrong?

By the way , do you know how to change the positions of columns ? (I have a template column which displays at first position by default, i would like it at the end )

Comment: @ArnaudAdigard http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-reordering-columns.html

Answer (score 0):

Your way will work if you'll be using MasterTableView

```
protected void RadGrid1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridColumn col in RadGrid1.MasterTableView.Columns)
    {
        if (col.UniqueName == "idAgir")
            col.HeaderText = "Numéro";
        if (col.UniqueName == "objet")
            col.HeaderText = "Titre du Ticket";
        if (col.UniqueName == "dateEtatIncident")
            col.HeaderText = "Date dernière intervention";
    }
    RadGrid1.Rebind(); 
}
```